# Renaming Azure Devops Build and Release pipeline through REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

trying to rename the pipelines build and release through REST API, I have gone through the official Microsoft documentation but didn't find any API's for this task. Did i miss any or we have such API's where by using build id/build name we can rename the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to make the change in the azure release page and look at the request that is being sent in the dev tools network tab? A couple of months ago I was able to learn how to retrieve some information that I was looking for by doing that.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Definitions-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) API to retrieve the requested body by pipeline definition ID.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Copy the response as body and use [Definitions-Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to rename the pipeline. Update the pipeline name of this revision.

[image]

Check the DevOps UI output.

[image]

The above workflow also applies to release pipeline, your need to change the REST API.

Using [Releases-Get release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the latest revision and using [Releases - Update Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to rename it